# turning off a sockets stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, twitter

I have a sockets stream that is attached to the twitter api and I need to find a way to toggle it on and off. I was attempting to use an array as a sort of counter and an if statement to break the stream when it filled to 10 bits of location data.

```
 var startArray = [];
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      if(startArray.length < 10){
        console.log('a user connected');
        // socket.on('twitter-stream', function(input) { 
         client.stream('statuses/filter', {locations:'-180,-90,180,90'}, function(s) {
              stream = s;
              stream.on('data', function(data) {
                // console.log(data);
                  // Does the JSON result have coordinates
                  // console.log(data.text)
                  if (data.coordinates){
                    if (data.coordinates !== null ){
                      //If so then build up some nice json and send out to web sockets

                      var outputPoint = {"lat": data.coordinates.coordinates[0],"lng": data.coordinates.coordinates[1]};
                      startArray.push(outputPoint);
                      io.emit("twitter-stream", outputPoint);

                      console.log(outputPoint);
                      console.log(startArray.length);
                      // console.log(data.text);
                      // console.log(data.text);

                      //Send out to web sockets channel.
                      io.emit('twitter-stream', outputPoint);
                    }
                  }
              });
          // }); // end client stream
        }) // end socket 'activate'
      };//end of if statement
    });//end of sockets`
```

^^
This section is in my server.js
This section is my sockets.js It was supposed to contain a button that was able to toggle the state of my stream, but that did not seem to work, whether it was turning the stream on or off. 
vv

```
var socket = io();

var locationsArray = [];

$(document).on('click', '#start-stream', function(){
    console.log('start-stream');

    socket.on('twitter-stream', function(tweet) {

    //only selects tweets with coordinates
        console.log(tweet);
        var coolShit = tweet;
        locationsArray.push(coolShit);
    });
})
```